# Using tastypie to retrieve data from foreign key

Tags: python, django, tastypie

These are two models in my Django app :

## models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(user,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField()

class Unposted(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Posts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upload_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

I'm trying to retrieve data from `Posts` using an API request to `Unposted`. 
Here's what I have until now but I'm unsure how to get data from the `Posts` model. Right now I just get a JSON response with only the `upload_at` field.

## resources.py

```
class UnpostedResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Unposted.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'unposted'
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a separate model to store the "posted/unposted" status of articles instead of having that info directly in the Posts model?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, u can just import your Posts model and then just by for loop make an array with posts models using foreign key from unposted to filter your posts =) Sounds weird and I'm not sure about effectiveness, but looks pretty nice. It will look smth like:

```
queryset = Posts.objects.filter(article_in=[get(i.article) for i in Unposted.objects.all()])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case, `Posts` is a foreignkey of `Unposted`, thus you need to define foreignkey field in the resource for the corresponding field in model, [this tutorial](https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#tastypie.fields.RelatedField.related_name) maybe can help you.